# Pytest calling different python interpreter (due to border effects)

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I need to test some code which has border effects so my tests need to have different Python interpreter.

Is there a way to tell **pytest** to use a new Python instance of the python interpreter for a given Test Case.

For example, I have a class C1 that sets an environment which is needed before instantiating another class C2 (I know, not a proper implementation :) ). I need to test:
* Class C1 is instantiated, then C2 is instantiated => OK
* Class C2 is instantiated => Raise exception

The following code would not be proper because of the border effect

```
def test_OK():
    C1()
    C2()

def test_NOK():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        C2()
```

I used a workaround by creating external files run with **subprocess** but it is ugly like hell.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import pytest

test_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
python_lib = test_dir.parent / "PythonLib"


no_standard = """
from a661test import TestFramework
from a661libgen_rev6_v1 import Label
framework = TestFramework()
framework.create_df([Label(1).define()])
"""

with_standard = """
from a661test import TestFramework
from a661libgen_rev6_v1 import Label, Standard_rev6_v1
Standard_rev6_v1()
framework = TestFramework()
framework.create_df([Label(1).define()])
"""

class Test_Framework_Nominal:
    def tc_A661_TESTFRAMEWORK_FRAMEWORK_TC_R_01(self, monkeypatch):
        """Checking an exception is raised when Standard not set"""
        monkeypatch.setenv("PYTHONPATH", str(python_lib))
        script = Path("script.py")
        script.write_text(no_standard)
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            subprocess.run(["python", str(script)], check=True)

    def tc_A661_TESTFRAMEWORK_FRAMEWORK_TC_N_02(self, monkeypatch):
        """Checking no exception is raised if Standard is set"""
        monkeypatch.setenv("PYTHONPATH", str(python_lib))
        script = Path("script.py")
        script.write_text(with_standard)
        subprocess.run(["python", str(script)], check=True)
```

Is there some magic option, or plugin / setting of *conftest.py* that would allow something like:

```
@pytest.mark.new_python_instance
def test_OK():
    C1()
    C2()

@pytest.mark.new_python_instance
def test_NOK():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        C2()
```

Thanks

Comment: Usually, you do it the other way - run the tests for all supported python versions (e.g. with `tox` or whatever) and conditionally skip the test that should be executed with selected interpreter only.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for the tip about today but here it’s not about testing with different versions but rather testing with different “instances” of a given python interpreter.

Comment: You can also configure testing with different "instances" of the same interpreter (whatever that means - same executable with different settings?). Otherwise, you have to fork a new process like you're doing already, there's no magic in Python for substituting a running process.

Comment: @hoefling  That indeed seems an interesting way to explore. So you can create several "tox configurations" name with the same interpreters?

Comment: IIRC yes, but I don't know what your exact requirements are. Check out the [environment settings](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#tox-environment-settings) for stuff you can modify.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Search for similar answers, did you got it finally?

Comment: @atline I was helping a friend to ask and he used a different approach. Myself had a similar issue and I solved it by removing the border effect (I have reset the state machine before running some tests). Otherwise, the approach to use tox seems like a good idea.